# Use of installed libraries

Tags: python

A Python script starts with:

```
from pathlib import Path
import sqlite3
```

which I read as an initialization of Libraries needed to run the rest of the script.  However if the following error is returned in the terminal:

```
ImportError: No module named pathlib
```

I am uncertain how to interpret this. One assumption is that the `pathlib` library is uninstalled. However on the local system Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 are installed (I believe one was system pre-installed).

How can a library be asserted to exist? In case it is missing, how can it be installed?

Comment: Are you running the script with Python 2.7 or 3.4? The answer varies greatly depending on the version since [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is in the standard library in 3.4+.

Comment: on OS X there's are Python launchers for versions 2 and 3.  I am getting the same error message in each instance.  How can this be verified?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install it first

```
pip install pathlib
```

And with that your code should work.

Comment: Note that this only applies to Python 2.7. [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is in the standard library in 3.4+.

Comment: A link to the project would be useful: [pathlib on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib/)

Comment: @wjandrea what are you talking about, pip is one of the standard package manager applications in python, this applies even up to python3.8.

Comment: I'm not talking about `pip`. You don't need to install `pathlib` in 3.4+ since it's in the standard library.

Comment: You are right, however, if it is not accessible by his system then it stands to reason that he is not using a version of python where pathlib is a standard library

Comment: @maestro.inc I ran that installer `Successfully built pathlib
Installing collected packages: pathlib
Successfully installed pathlib-1.0.1`  However the same error cropped up when running the script.  Corrupt installation?